# how to register more than 10 apps in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, registration

Anyone knows any "legal" way to surpass the 10-app-limit Google imposes?
I wouldn't mind to pay, or anything, but I wasn't able to find a way to have more
than 10 apps and can't either remove one.

Answer (score 3):

Call or write to Google! Google's policies are very exact and very strict, because they are catering to *thousands* of developers, and thus need those standards and uniformity. But if you have a good reason for needing more than 10, and you can get a real person at the end of a telephone line, I'd think you'd have a good chance of getting the limit raised.

Alternatively, you could just get a friend or co-worker to register. That seems like it ought to be legal...but check the User Agreement first.

Comment: We'd prefer legitimate developers simply ask for more IDs.

Comment: Good to hear. I'm sure developers would prefer that too :)