# Why Google App Engine has limitation of max 10 active applications?

Tags: google-app-engine

I think question is pretty descriptive.

I have read following phrase in app engine documentation as well as books "`You can have up to 10 active applications created by a given developer account. You can disable an application to reclaim a slot`", RETAIL, 2012, Programming Google App Engine, 2nd Edition, OReilly.

However, they didn't said why or what's the reason(s)?
Does Google cannot count more than 10? :)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294618/how-to-register-more-than-10-apps-in-google-app-engine

Comment: that all seems out of date to me. I have more then 10 simply from enabling billing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason is to avoid spam or abuse of service. If you can create unlimited number of apps you can basically create a farm of servers that can do unlimited things that can attack other websites or spam emails.

Enabling billing will verify your identity and can easily get caught once you violate their terms of service.

Comment: It's good idea. I had not think about it. The limitation of 10 doesn't make sense if Google is looking for credit cards since doesn't charge cards by number of applications. I think your guess is rational.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more, simply enable billing. You can then have as many as you like.